# Please merge thread-priorities with thread-priority

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I tried to edit the questions so they are tagged correctly, but I can't see all of them (are they deleted or hidden?)

Tags: [thread-priorities](/questions/tagged/thread-priorities) (21) [thread-priority](/questions/tagged/thread-priority) (7)

Comment: What makes you think there are some you can't see?

Comment: When I click on "thread-priority" I see zero not 7 questions.

Comment: Well, I finished the re-taging to [thread-priorities] but I'm actually not too happy about it, now that I think about it. [thread-priority] looks nicer...

Comment: Agreed, it does... is it difficult to globally rename a tag?  I'll get to work on what I have visibility to if you like

Comment: Only mods can do merges and renames (or validate synonyms with a single vote). There is no mass tagging tool available to mere mortals. Let's switch all that back to [thread-priority], 28 Qs isn't that much work.

Comment: I did what I could... it says "6 questions tagged with thread-priorities" and I can't see them

Comment: I don't know why you didn't see those questions. Ignored tags maybe? Or were you on the "unanswered" tab in the question view? Anyway, it is completed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All done, questions tagged [thread-priorities](/questions/tagged/thread-priorities) retagged to [thread-priority](/questions/tagged/thread-priority), with some cleanup along the way.

The plural tag is orphan, should go away soon-ish by itself. I don't think a synonym is required.